# Sources not analysed by SonarQube with MSBuild

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm trying to build/analyze several C# projects with SonarQube & MSBuild but, even though the analysis finished successfully and without any errors, it seems that not all sources are analyzed.

For example I have this project called "Filter" with 6 .cs files which are discovered and indexed during analysis (AssemblyInfo.cs, FilterApplicationView.cs, FilterFindView.cs, FilterSaveView.cs, FilterView.cs, RegistrationManager.cs) but only 2 of them appear in the Lines of Code measures page of the SonarQube dashboard (AssemblyInfo.cs and RegistrationManager.cs).

Can someone help me find the cause for this and how to fix it?

This is the Jenkins output for the analysis:

```
11:49:11.954 INFO: -------------  Scan Filter
11:49:12.123 INFO: Load server rules
11:49:12.184 DEBUG: GET 200 http://hostname:port/sonar/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=61ms
11:49:12.194 INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=71ms
11:49:12.255 DEBUG: Initializers : 
11:49:12.255 INFO: Base dir: C:\deliv_jenkins\workspace\workspace\Summit_Sonar_Test_Windows\FT_Front\Filter
11:49:12.255 INFO: Working dir: C:\deliv_jenkins\workspace\workspace\Summit_Sonar_Test_Windows\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\org.misys.summit-CSharp-Temp_org.misys.summit-CSharp-Temp_6E53A807-9ABD-4614-8BBA-F1EA5B310FD8
11:49:12.255 INFO: Source paths: AssemblyInfo.cs, FilterApplicationView.cs, FilterFindView.cs, FilterSaveView.cs, FilterView.cs, RegistrationManager.cs, App.ico, FilterApplicationView.resx, FilterFindView.resx, FilterSaveView.resx, FilterView.resx
11:49:12.256 INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
11:49:12.256 INFO: Index files
11:49:12.268 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.c : **/*.c,**/*.h
11:49:12.268 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C++ were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cpp : **/*.cc,**/*.cpp,**/*.cxx,**/*.c++,**/*.hh,**/*.hpp,**/*.hxx,**/*.h++,**/*.ipp
11:49:12.268 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Objective-C were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.objc : **/*.m
11:49:12.269 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language RPG were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.rpg : **/*.rpg,**/*.rpgle,**/*.rpg,**/*.rpgle
11:49:12.269 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JavaScript were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.js : **/*.js
11:49:12.269 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language PL/SQL were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.plsql : **/*.sql,**/*.pks,**/*.pkb
11:49:12.269 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language C# were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.cs : **/*.cs
11:49:12.269 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language JSP were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.jsp : **/*.jsp
11:49:12.270 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Java were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.java : **/*.java,**/*.jav
11:49:12.270 DEBUG: Declared extensions of language Visual Basic .NET were converted to sonar.lang.patterns.vbnet : **/*.vb
11:49:12.274 DEBUG: Language of file 'FilterApplicationView.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
11:49:12.275 DEBUG: Language of file 'FilterFindView.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
11:49:12.275 DEBUG: Language of file 'AssemblyInfo.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
11:49:12.293 INFO: Analyzer working directory contains 5 .pb file(s)
11:49:12.318 DEBUG: Language of file 'FilterView.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
11:49:12.323 DEBUG: Language of file 'FilterSaveView.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
11:49:12.329 DEBUG: Language of file 'RegistrationManager.cs' is detected to be 'cs'
11:49:12.366 INFO: 6 files indexed
11:49:12.371 INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
11:49:12.380 WARN: ----------------------------------------------------------------
11:49:12.380 WARN: Sonargraph Integration: Skipping project Filter [org.misys.summit-CSharp-Temp:org.misys.summit-CSharp-Temp:6E53A807-9ABD-4614-8BBA-F1EA5B310FD8], since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile [SonarQube].
11:49:12.380 WARN: ----------------------------------------------------------------
11:49:12.384 DEBUG: Code colorizer, supported languages: jsp
11:49:13.179 DEBUG: 'C' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.179 DEBUG: 'CPP' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.179 DEBUG: 'Objective-C' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.179 DEBUG: 'gcov' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.180 DEBUG: 'llvm-cov' skipped because there is no related file     in current project
11:49:13.180 DEBUG: 'cppunit' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.180 DEBUG: 'VisualStudioCoverage' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.180 DEBUG: 'bullseye' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.180 DEBUG: 'RPG sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.180 DEBUG: 'JavaScript Squid Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'PL/SQL Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'FindBugs Sensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'SurefireSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoItSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'JaCoCoOverallSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'JavaSquidSensor' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.181 DEBUG: 'VB.NET' skipped because there is no related file in current project
11:49:13.184 DEBUG: Sensors : Lines Sensor -> Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5] -> SCM Sensor -> C# -> Coverage Report Import -> Coverage Report Import -> Unit Test Results Import -> XmlFileSensor -> Coverage Report Import -> Coverage Report Import -> Unit Test Results Import -> Zero Coverage Sensor -> Code Colorizer Sensor -> CPD Block Indexer
11:49:13.185 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
11:49:13.195 INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=10ms
11:49:13.195 INFO: Sensor Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5]
11:49:13.197 INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------
11:49:13.197 INFO: Sonargraph: Skipping project Filter [org.misys.summit-CSharp-Temp:org.misys.summit-CSharp-Temp:6E53A807-9ABD-4614-8BBA-F1EA5B310FD8], since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile.
11:49:13.197 INFO: ----------------------------------------------------------------
11:49:13.197 INFO: Sensor Sonar-Sonargraph-Plugin [3.5] (done) | time=2ms
11:49:13.197 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
11:49:13.209 INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=12ms
11:49:13.209 INFO: Sensor C#
11:49:13.214 INFO: SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: false
11:49:13.214 INFO: Importing analysis results from C:\deliv_jenkins\workspace\workspace\Summit_Sonar_Test_Windows\.sonarqube\out\Filter_AnyCPU_Debug_3557\output-cs
11:49:13.259 INFO: Importing Roslyn report
11:49:13.322 INFO: Sensor C# (done) | time=112ms
11:49:13.322 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import
11:49:13.322 DEBUG: No coverage property. Skip Sensor
11:49:13.322 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import (done) | time=0ms
11:49:13.322 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import
11:49:13.322 DEBUG: No coverage property. Skip Sensor
11:49:13.322 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import (done) | time=0ms
11:49:13.322 INFO: Sensor Unit Test Results Import
11:49:13.322 DEBUG: No unit test results property. Skip Sensor
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor Unit Test Results Import (done) | time=1ms
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=0ms
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import
11:49:13.323 DEBUG: No coverage property. Skip Sensor
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import (done) | time=0ms
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import
11:49:13.323 DEBUG: No coverage property. Skip Sensor
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor Coverage Report Import (done) | time=0ms
11:49:13.323 INFO: Sensor Unit Test Results Import
11:49:13.324 DEBUG: No unit test results property. Skip Sensor
11:49:13.324 INFO: Sensor Unit Test Results Import (done) | time=1ms
11:49:13.324 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
11:49:13.333 INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=9ms
11:49:13.333 INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
11:49:13.333 INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=0ms
11:49:13.334 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
11:49:13.334 INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs
11:49:13.334 DEBUG: No CpdMapping for language cs
11:49:13.334 INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=0ms
```

Comment: I have the same issue, some projects get scanned and others not. The projects that are not scanned have this: 
SonarAnalyzer.Scanner needs to be executed: false